# Removing a line from a PDF document

Tags: pdf, editing, documents

I have a series of simple PDF documents that have a heading in them that I need to remove. The documents contain actual text, they're not silly Photo-based PDFs. I don't know what they were produced with, but I got them from a government department, so I wouldn't be surprised if it was an old version of some Adobe tool.

So all I want is some little free tool I can use for this.

I don't care what platform the software runs on, as I've got everything available (okay, not Windows 3.1, if you answer with that, I'll report you to the clown-authorities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kind of tricky - PDF is not really meant for editing, as you probably know.

You could try [Scribus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribus). It has a nice PDF import, and can also export to PDF. It will probably not round-trip perfectly, but might be good enough.

You could also have a look at [PDFTK](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). It cannot remove individual lines from a file, but it allows splitting & merging of pages, so you could first extract the pages to modify, and work only on these in Scribus.

Of course, Wikipedia also has a list :-):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software